# Generic methods to whom I can pass String parameter

Tags: java

I have a string-like class `myString`. To its methods, I would like to pass generic types T, where T can either be a string, or an object of `myString`. What I have done so far is put the methods of the String class that I use (such as `charAt(), size()`) into an interface `myInterface`, and written something like this:

```
class myString implements myInterface{     
  public <T extends myInterface> void mymethod(
         T inputString){
  }
}
```

What I want is that `inputString` can be either a String or a `myString` object.

However, I get an error that says `String is not a valid type for T`.

What I am doing wrong?

PS: This is my first question on Stack, so pl. bear with me.

Comment: `String` doesn't implement your interface `myInterface`, so `myInterface` is not going to work as a polymorphic type for `String`. However, `String` _does_ implement an interface called [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). Maybe you should use that instead.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried to accept all answers and comment, since they all gave me new information that solved the problem; however, I was only able to accept one answer. Hence I accepted the one at the top.

Comment: Right, you can only accept one answer.  But you can upvote all of them. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `java.lang.CharSequence` interface instead of `MyInterface` to define your own string class. And your method reference the generic type should be:

```
public <T extends CharSequence> void mymethod(T inputString) {
    ...
}
```

BTW, `CharSequence` does not have `size()` method, so you should use `length()` instead.

Refer to

- https://github.com/osglworks/java-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osgl/util/StrBase.java
- https://github.com/osglworks/java-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osgl/util/Str.java
- https://github.com/osglworks/java-tool/blob/master/src/main/java/org/osgl/util/FastStr.java

Answer (score 0):

`String` class not implement `myInterface` so you can't pass object of type `String` to method `mymethod`. Because you place this restriction `<T extends myInterface>`. So you can invoke this method only with objects that extends `myInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way in Java to do exactly what you want.  In Java, you can say that a generic parameter must belong to a certain superclass, but that's the only kind of limitation you can give it (other than `T super T1` which isn't commonly used and won't help you here).  In your case, you'd need to find a class that both `String` and `myString` are subclasses of, or an interface that they both implement.  Also, if your method needs to use `charAt()` and `length()` [not `size()`], the common class or interface has to define those methods.

In your case, I'd suggest that you have your `myString` class implement [`CharSequence.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)  `String` also implements `CharSequence`, so you'd be able to say `public <T extends CharSequence> myMethod(...)`.  Your method would then be able to use any method defined in `CharSequence`, including `charAt()` and `length()`.  However, it wouldn't be able to use any other methods, even if they're defined both for `String` and for `myString`.

I believe there are dynamic languages in which you *could* define a method that can take any class, as long as the class supports the operations you tell it you need.  If I'm not mistaken, this is called duck typing.  However, I'm not an expert in that kind of language, but I do know that Java isn't one of them.